# Check, if word has a same end and start in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for how can I check if word has a same end and start. There is my code:

JavaScript:

```js
function Check() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;

  if (value == startsWith(endsWith()) && value == endsWith(startsWith())) {
    return alert("Yes");

  } else {
    return alert("No");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" style="margin:20px;" type="text"><br>
<button id="button" onclick="Check();">Check</button>
<p id="demo" style="color:white;">Answer</p>
```

Comment: `value.endsWith(value[0])`

Comment: example input and output ?

Comment: both startsWith and endsWith methods checking first and last character of string ? explain it .

Comment: Did you mean starting and ending with the same character (eg, `Level`) ? Then, you should try `if(value[0] == value[value.length-1]) { alert('Yes'); } else { alert('No'); }`

Comment: does start and end mean the same letter? or the same word? or the same 3 letters? or something completely else?

Comment: Siva, Yes.
Rahul, Yeah

Comment: Mayme you mean [palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090974/check-if-a-string-is-a-palindrome-in-javascript/31091045#31091045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below function. 
I am comparing first character and last character of your input string.

```
function Check() {
  var value = document.getElementById("input").value;

  if (value.charAt(0) === value.charAt(value.length - 1)) {
    return alert("Yes");

  } else {
    return alert("No");
  }
}
```

Comment: This one works thanks, but alert("No"); is not working

Comment: Edited. Now check.

Comment: Please mark as answer or up vote. So others can use it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the first and last character of the string:

```
if(value[0] == value[value.length-1]) 
{
   alert('Yes');
}
else
{ 
   alert('No');
}
```

Comment: Glad to solve your problem. Please mark it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.length - 1` to get the index of the last character of the string.

```js
function check(str) {
  if (str[0] === str[str.length - 1]) {
    alert('yes')
  } else {
    alert('no');
  }
}

check('test');
check('tests');
```

To check first/last `n` characters you can do this.

```js
function checkMore(str, amount) {
  if (str[0] !== str[str.length - 1]) {
    alert('no');
    return;
  } else if (amount !== 1) {
    return checkMore(str.slice(1, str.length - 1), amount - 1);
  }
  alert('yes');
}

checkMore('stests', 1);
checkMore('stests', 2);
checkMore('stests', 3);
```

And to check the whole string (basically checking if the string is palindrome).

```js
function checkPalindrome(str) {
  if (str.length === 0 || str.length === 1) {
    alert('yes');
    return;
  }
  if (str[0] !== str[str.length - 1]) {
    alert('no');
    return;
  }
  checkPalindrome(str.slice(1, str.length - 1));
}

checkPalindrome('car');
checkPalindrome('carac');
checkPalindrome('carrac');
```

Comment: Thanks for your work, I appreciate that, but I already found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match()` or `indexOf()`. Both work, but both search the whole string. It is more efficient to extract the substring in the relevant place and compare it with the one you expect there:

```js
function Check ( word ) {
  return word.charAt(0) == word.charAt( word.length - 1 )
}
```

```html
<button tye="button" onclick="alert( Check('Hello') )">Check 'Hello'</button>
<button tye="button" onclick="alert( Check('HelloH') )">Check 'HelloH'</button>
```

Of course, you might as well use a regular expression, with a smart regex engine it should be efficient as well (and your code is more concise):

```js
function Check ( word ) {
  return /^(.).*\1$|^.$/.test( word )
}
```

```html
<button tye="button" onclick="alert( Check('Hello') )">Check 'Hello'</button>
<button tye="button" onclick="alert( Check('WoW') )">Check 'WoW'</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = "wow"
return (value[0] === value[value.length - 1] ? true : false)
```

0th index will contain starting character and value.length - 1 will contain ending character. If they are equal it will return true and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split('' )` to split a string by spaces, so into words. It splits it into an array, so you can compare index `[0]` to index `[length-1]`

For example

```
    function Check(string) {
        let arr = string.split(' ');
        return arr[0] == arr[arr.length-1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
if (/^(.).*\1$|^.$/.test(value))
    // first and last are same letter
```