# JavaScript - Find if string is a palindrome - Check for punctuation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve an exercise but the code shows errors. Here are the conditions given for the exercise:

> Return true if the given string is a palindrome. Otherwise, return false.
>
> 1. You'll need to remove punctuation and turn everything lower case in
>      order to check for palindromes.
> 2. We'll pass strings with varying formats, such as "racecar",
>          "RaceCar", and "race CAR" among others.

My attempt:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(",", "");
    str = str.replace(".", "");
    str = str.replace(":", "");
    str = str.replace(";", "");
    str = str.replace("-", "");
    str = str.replace(",", "");
    str = str.replace(" ", "");
    for (var i = 0; i <= (str.length / 2); i++) {
        if (str[i] != str.length - i) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So we need to guess errors or complete this exercise for you?

Comment: `str[i] != str.length-i` --- what this comparison is about? You're comparing a letter with... a number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Palindrome check in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813369/palindrome-check-in-javascript)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Not quite, this one has a bit of leniency for punctuation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were quite close.
Replace:

```
if (str[i] != str.length-i)
```

With:

```
if (str[i] != str[str.length - (i + 1)])
```

The last character of the string is at `str.length - (i + 1)`, and you forgot to get the actual character. Instead, you were comparing it with the index of that character.

Now, you could shorten the function a *lot*:

```
function checkPalindrome(str) {
    // remove punctuation, to lower case.
    str = str.replace(/[.,?:;\/() _-]/g, '').toLowerCase();
    // Compare the string with it's reversed version.
    return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: will `/[^a-z0-9]/g` be better to remove all non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: +one Removed my Duplicate

Comment: @Tushar: `checkPalindrom("rácecér")` will return `true`, for that regex.

Comment: I followed this code. Now I am getting the following error,
`assert.strictEqual(palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0"), true, "\"0_0 (: /-\\ :) 0-0\" is a palindrome");"0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0" is a palindrome: expected false to equal true`

Comment: @FahadUddin: In that case, you need to trim some more punctuation. I edited my answer.

Comment: Another way - `var y = x.match(/[a-zA-Z]*/g).join("").toLowerCase();`

Comment: @AdityaParab: Nope. That will ignore stuff like `éíô` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the info, mate. How do we catch those characters?

Comment: By only removing characters we don't want, instead of trying to get everything you _do_ want to match.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for the problem:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase() == str.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

In terms of performance this solution is faster than using a for loop or regular expression

Answer (score -3):

This is quite simple. just make and call below function:

`var isPalindrome = function(str){
     return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}`

Answer (score -4):

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var len = str.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++ ) {
        if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Optimized version

Source : [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111507/how-to-write-palindrome-in-javascript)

Comment: It's a placebo optimisation.

Comment: It would still be beneficial. (Not considering extremely large palindromes)

Comment: Eh, no. This completely ignores the question's requirement for the check to be case insensitive and to remove punctuation.