# Compare two words spelled backwards and forwards is same way in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var str = ("level");

arr = Array.from(str);

function repeat(arr) {

  let forward = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
  let backward = arr.reverse();

  console.log(forward);
  console.log(backward);

  if (forward === backward) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};


var result = repeat(arr);

console.log(result);
```

I keep getting results as false.

Comment: `forward` and `backward` will never be equal since both are different object(arrays are objects in js), so they are compared with the reference, so always result `false`.

Comment: Duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22111507/14032355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are comparing to different objects.

Convert them to string before compare:

```js
var str = ("level");

arr = Array.from(str);

function repeat(arr) {

  let forward = arr.slice(0, arr.length).join("");
  let backward = arr.reverse().join("");

  console.log(forward);
  console.log(backward);

  if (forward === backward) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};


var result = repeat(arr);

console.log(result);
```

The method of reversing the string is good, but you have many unnecesary steps. Here is a more optimized version:

```js
var str = "level";

function repeat(forward) {

  const backward = forward.split("").reverse().join("");

  console.log(forward);
  console.log(backward);

  return forward === backward;
}


var result = repeat(str);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you compare two arrays, you are not comparing their contents, but instead the array objects themselves. Because **forward** and **backward** are different arrays, they are not equal to each-other.

I'd suggest either looping through each element in both arrays and comparing them to each-other, or joining all the elements into strings and comparing those.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain things that you can do with this

**1)** You can spread string in an array because `str` is a string and strings are iterable in JS.

```
let arr = [...str];
```

**2)** You can use spread in-place of slice to make it more readable

```
  let forward = [...arr];
```

**3)** Since [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is in place, so you can spread it into a new array.

```
let backward = [...arr.reverse()];
```

**4)** You can have multiple options here first to use `join` and then compare because strings are primitive and compared with the value that is already answered.
So you can also use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) here:

```
forward.every((s, i) => s === backward[i]);
```

```js
var str = "level";

let arr = [...str];

function repeat(arr) {
  let forward = [...arr];
  let backward = [...arr.reverse()];

  console.log(forward);
  console.log(backward);
  return forward.every((s, i) => s === backward[i]);
}

var result = repeat(arr);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
str === [...str].reverse().join("") // result is true for 'level'
```